# Is the kernel of a ring homomorphism a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following link proves that if $f:R \to R'$ is a ring homormorphism, then $\ker(f)$ is a subring of $R:$

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kernel_of_Ring_Homomorphism_is_Subring

But an alternative source claims that $\ker(f)$ isn't a ring (See Theorem $3.5$):

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/ringdefs.pdf

Which is the right convention, and if neither is particularly right, which one is better?

Comment: Do you mean for rings to have a multiplicative identity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you should have read the paragraph after Theorem $3.5$:

> This last theorem is probably why some people do not insist that rings contain 1. Kernels
>   of ring homomorphisms have all the properties of a subring except they almost never contain
>   the multiplicative identity. So if we want ring theory to mimic group theory by having
>   kernels of ring homomorphisms be subrings, then we should not insist that subrings contain 1
>   (and thus perhaps not even insist that rings contain 1). Then kernels of ring homomorphisms
>   could be called subrings.

His definition of a ring is not the one used in the first link:

> Definition $1.1$. A ring is a set $R$ equipped with two operations $+$ (addition) and $×$
>   (multiplication) such that $R$ is an abelian group under addition (with identity denoted $0$
>   and the inverse of $a$ denoted $−a$), while multiplication is associative with an identity element
>   $1$. Finally, multiplication distributes over addition: $x(y+z) = xy+xz$ and $(x+y)z = xz+yz$
>   for all $x, y$, and $z$ in $R.$

Comment: In the case where rings are defined as having a multiplicative identity, kernels are not subrings?

Comment: Yes, this is well explained in the proof of theorem $3.5$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is best thought of as an ideal. Every ideal is a subring, but *not necessarily with unit*. Some authors only consider rings with unit, hence the different conventions.